# active record where foreign key can be anything of two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, foreign-key-relationship

I have a User Model.

I have a Friend Model with columns invitee_id and Inviter_id and status. Status is used as flag whether friend request has been accepted or not. Inviter_id is the id of the user who sending the friend request and invitee_id is the user who is receiving the friend request.Please check inline comment.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friends // now i want to search all the friends with accepted friend request. (sent or received both.)
    has_many :pending_friend_requests,:class_name => "Friend", :foreign_key=>"invitee_id", :conditions => {:status => 0}
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Question is how to fetch all the friend with accepted friend requests.. sent or received as there are two foreign columns. invitee_id or Inviter_id

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @bor1s question is how to fetch all the friend with accepted friend requests.. sent or received

Comment: So I see that you have no user_id in your Frien model, so you can use something like this in your relation: has_many :friends, :foreign_key => "invitee_id" and then just user.friends. I think it should fetch all friends no metter what status they have

Comment: @bor1s I think u didnt read of question clearly. I am having two columns. ie invitee_id and inviter_id and if I am sending you a friend request then My user_id will be saved in inviter_id and your user_id will be saved in Invitee_id. So if i do the things tell my you then in that cause I will get all of my friends to whom I sent  friend request. I hope you got what i am trying to say.

Comment: Hm .. maybe this will help: user.friends.where("status = true")

Comment: No.. that will not work for sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) is what you need.

Updated

Altough you say you don't, I think, you do need a self-referential many-to-many relation.
Instead of making an associations for pending requests, you could make a named scope. And after that, you could get all the friends you invited by `User.find(params[:id]).friends.accepted`.

What I can't understand is whether you want user.friends to retrieve both the ones who invited me and the ones invited by me OR only one of these.

Because of your namings (inviter and invitee) I suppose it is the second case. An it is covered in the screencast. It is done by creating additional *inverted* association (Ryan talks about that in the end).

But if it's the first one, the easiest solution would be to make two rows for each inviter-invitee pair. You could use this [gem](https://github.com/sjlombardo/acts_as_network) to simplify things, but it acts the same way I told.

If it doesn't help, try to specify your question.

Comment: I am having two columns. ie invitee_id and inviter_id and if I am sending you a friend request then My user_id will be saved in inviter_id and your user_id will be saved in Invitee_id. So if i do the things tell my you then in that cause I will get all of my friends to whom I sent friend request.

Answer (score 0):

The `has_many` sets up the relations.  Use `scope` for conditions.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :invitees, :through => :friends
    has_many :friends, :foreign_key=>"inviter_id"

    def accepted_invitees
       invitees.where(:friends => {:accepted => true })
    end
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invitee, :class_name => "User"
    belongs_to :inviter, :class_name => "User"

    # needs accepted column
end
```

However, this is way to confusing because of the way that the models and columns are setup. If I were doing this I would do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
    has_many :friendships

    def accepted_friends
        friends.where(:friendships => {:accepted => true })
    end

end

class Friendships < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user # change inviter_id to user_id
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User" # change invitee_id to friend_id

    # needs accepted column
end
```

Comment: yaa seems i am doing wrong.. Lemme check it, I will be back for sure.